# MySQL/JDBC: Can a commit on server get missed on client?

Tags: mysql, transaction, java, jdbc

I am wondering about when conducting a transaction of one or two updates/inserts from a JDBC client to MySQL Server over the network...

In the event of losing the network during the commit, can I get stuck with the commit occurring on the server, but not being known to have happened on the client?

Comment: Is JDBC saying that the 'connection is down'?  Or is it 'auto-reconnecting'?

Comment: Thx.  I'm not working on a bug.  I'm asking if the driver can say that the server committed or not, reliably, such as when a disconnect occurs about the time of the commit.